# Backbone child view events not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events

I'm a little confused as to why my event is not firing on a child view. I usually set a `$el` attribute but in this instance I am reusing the child view multiple times so I'm setting the `className` attribute but it's still not firing.

Here's my code:

Child view (simplified):

```
var LogbookEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({

    className: 'log-entry',
    collection: Logbook,
    template: _.template($('#logbook-entry-view').html()),

    events: {
        "click .edit-log": "editLog",
        "click .popup": "modalHandler"
    },

    render: function(model) {
        return this.template(model);
    },

    editLog: function(event) {
        var target = $(event.currentTarget);
        var id = $(target).data('id');
        var url = target.attr("href");
        var modal = $(target).data('modal');
        this.loadModal(modal, url);
        return false;
    }
})
```

Parent view method:

```
displaySkillsByCat: function() {
    var entryView = new LogbookEntryView();
    _.each(_.keys(app.data), function(cat) {
        $("#logbook-tabs ." + cat).removeClass('disabled');
        $("#" + cat).append(app.template);
        _.each(app.data[cat], function(item) {
            $("#" + cat + " .logbook-list").append(entryView.render(item.attributes));
        });
    })

    return this;
},
    groupSkillsByCategory: function(){
  var cats = _.uniq( this.collection.pluck('cat_group') );
  _.each(cats,  function(cat, index){
    app.data['cat' + cat] = Logbook.where({'cat_group': cat});
  });
},
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you say you're reusing a view, but in practice, you're not using it at all.

You're just passing data through the `render` function which returns a string, without any events or anything related to Backbone.

So the first step is to fix the child view class.

- `collection` property on a view isn't meant to be used that way, so remove that.
- A view should fill its `el` or `$el` (jQuery equivalent) with a template.
- `render` should return `this` as a standard.

```
var LogbookEntryView = Backbone.View.extend({
    className: 'log-entry',
    template: _.template($('#logbook-entry-view').html()),

    events: {
        "click .edit-log": "editLog",
        "click .popup": "modalHandler"
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },

    editLog: function(event) {
        var $target = $(event.currentTarget);
        var id = event.currentTarget.id;
        var url = $target.attr("href");
        var modal = $target.data('modal');
        this.loadModal(modal, url);
        return false;
    },
    modalHandler: function() {},
    loadModal: function() {}
});
```

Then, in the parent view, you could simplify it a bit.

- Use [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each) directly, you do not need `_.keys`. If it's a Backbone collection, you could use `app.data.each(...)`.
- Avoid using the [core jQuery function](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) in a loop. Instead, [cache the object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40321584/1218980) in a variable, then use it in the loop.
- Instead of appending the string of the sub view, create a new view and append its `el` DOMElement.

```
displaySkillsByCat: function() {
    var entryView = new LogbookEntryView();
    _.each(app.data, function(entries, cat) {
        $("#logbook-tabs ." + cat).removeClass('disabled');
        $("#" + cat).append(app.template);

        // select this element once instead of each iteration
        var $list = $("#" + cat + " .logbook-list");
        _.each(entries, function(item) {

            // here, use `.el` to get the sub-view's element
            $list.append(new LogbookEntryView({ model: item }).render().el);
        });
    })

    return this;
},
```

---

The above is a simple fix for your situation, but if you don't keep track of the sub views and they are listening to a Backbone model, there could be memory leaks.

Here's a more [efficient way to render a list with Backbone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44034868/1218980).

Comment: First off thanks for the really detailed response, this was really helpful. It makes complete sense now, why my events weren't firing.

Secondly thanks for the tips and link on best practice, I'm new to Backbone this year and best practice is something am struggling with.

Comment: I do have a couple of comments, re the code. For some reason _.each(app.data) just returns undefined, that's why i was using_.keys(). I've updated my initial question to add the code for the where app.data is being populated (groupSkillsByCategory()), maybe you can see why a standard _.each look is failing.

Comment: Also now the child view is creating a wrapper div  with a className of "log-entry" around my actually template. To counter this I've updated my child view adding a tagName ="tr" and removing <tr class="log-entry"> from my actual template. However now its not rendering the actual parsed HTML, its just created an empty tr with that className.